# Getting target of event that fired

Tags: java, events, onclicklistener, gxt

I'm trying to find a way to tell what object fired my onClick event. I have a checkbox that currently fires once when the checkbox is clicked and fires twice when the label is clicked. I want to be able to ignore when the label is clicked.

I have found some code that is similar to what I want [here](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?93365-Radio-CheckBox-event-listener-onClick-fires-twice-on-label) which explains how to use a gxt FieldEvent, but i'm using a gxt BaseEvent and i'm not able to change it to a field event. Is there an equivalent function to .getTarget() for BaseEvents?

TLDR; Does anyone know how to do an equivalent of what's [here](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?93365-Radio-CheckBox-event-listener-onClick-fires-twice-on-label) but using gxt BaseEvent rather than FieldEvent?

Answer (score 0):

According to the api here:
http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/gxt-2.2.5/docs/api/com/extjs/gxt/ui/client/event/BaseEvent.html

you should be able to call the `getSource()` method and then extract the name. Was this what you were looking for?

Comment: I've just done a test on this using:
    MessageBox.Alert("Test",be.getSource().toString(), null)
and it just returned blank each time so I don't think that's what I want

Comment: Does the getSource() return null? Then you have two options: 1) Api incomplete 2) you have a null object, time to initialize, time to debug.